# objective c TableView cell Detail ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

My `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    appdataModel = [AppDataModel getInstance]; 
    appdataModel.newsApiUrl = homePagesUrl;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"plist"];
    contactsArray  = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile :path];
    [self GetHomePageData];


   /**** for left side menu ***/

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sideBarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sideBarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }

}
```

i am getting data from this method :

```
-(void)GetHomePageData{

   // url_to_load = homePagesNews;

    NSString *urlString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newsApiUrl];
    NSURL *url            = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *GETReply      = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

}
```

for show data in UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    details = res[indexPath.row];

    NSString *titleNews = details[@"title"];
    NSString *newsDateTime = details[@"datetime"];
    NSString *NewsImageName = details[@"featured_image"];

    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:NewsImageName ];
   // UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NewsImageName]]];

    customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews;
    customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime;
    //customCell.customImageView.image =image;

    NSURL *imageUrl=[details valueForKey:@"featured_image"];

    [customCell.customImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];
    //[tableView reloadData];

    return customCell;
}
```

for show detils data in a tableview after select a cell

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
    //s NSIndexPath *path = Nil;
     NSString *titleString  = Nil;

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    titleString = [res objectAtIndex:path.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setTitle:titleString];

    }
}
```

But it's now working . can some help me to solve this ..Thanks in advance

Comment: I could not able to get what you are asking.

Comment: Can you please elaborate which part is not working ?

Comment: after selecting row application crash .. and giving me this error [__NSDictionaryM stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: You using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: method anywhere in your code, if yes please show that part.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString *NewsImageName = details[@"featured_image"];` ,it is dictionary not a string!, you could delete that line.

`[details valueForKey:@"featured_image"]` it is string, but you are assigning it to `NSURL` directly.

`NSURL *imageUrl=[details valueForKey:@"featured_image"];`

replace it as follows

```
NSURL* imageUrl= [NSURL URLWithString:[details valueForKey:@"featured_image"]];
```

Comment: i want to this NSString *titleNews = details[@"title"];
    NSString *newsDateTime = details[@"datetime"];
    NSString *NewsImageName = details[@"featured_image"]; but failed  :(

Comment: You should provide your json object in your question or you should put a debug point at `details = res[indexPath.row];` and follow your object in that delegate method.

Comment: i added from where i getting data